# apply query to each part of table individually

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I need to run some query against each rowset in a table (Azure SQL):

```
ID    CustomerID     MsgTimestamp            Msg
-------------------------------------------------
1     123            2017-01-01 10:00:00     Hello
2     123            2017-01-01 10:01:00     Hello again
3     123            2017-01-01 10:02:00     Can you help me with my order
4     123            2017-01-01 11:00:00     Are you still there
5     456            2017-01-01 10:07:00     Hey I'm a new customer
```

What I want to do is to extract "chat session" for every customer from message records, that is, if the gap between someone's two consecutive messages is less than 30 minutes, they belong to the same session. I need to record the start and end time of each session in a new table. In the example above, start and end time of the first session for customer 123 are 10:00 and 10:02.

I know I can always use cursor and temp table to achieve that goal, but I'm thinking about utilizing any pre-built mechanism to reach better performance. Please kindly give me some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions instead of cursor. Something like this should work:

```
declare @t table (ID int, CustomerID int, MsgTimestamp datetime2(0), Msg nvarchar(100))
insert @t values
(1,     123,            '2017-01-01 10:00:00',     'Hello'),
(2,     123,            '2017-01-01 10:01:00',     'Hello again'),
(3,     123,            '2017-01-01 10:02:00',     'Can you help me with my order'),
(4,     123,            '2017-01-01 11:00:00',     'Are you still there'),
(5,     456,            '2017-01-01 10:07:00',     'Hey I''m a new customer')

;with x as (
  select *, case when datediff(minute, lag(msgtimestamp, 1, '19000101') over(partition by customerid order by msgtimestamp), msgtimestamp) > 30 then 1 else 0 end as g
  from @t
),
y as (
  select *, sum(g) over(order by msgtimestamp) as gg
  from x
)
select customerid, min(msgtimestamp), max(msgtimestamp) 
from y
group by customerid, gg
```

Comment: So cool! I once though about using window function but don't know how exactly to implement. and your use of "session marker" (column g and gg) is awesome!